# Sitecore Experience Accelerator (SXA) Installation Error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-sxa

The following error is occurring during installation of Sitecore Experience Accelerator (v 1.6 rev 180103) to Sitecore 9.0 (Update 1, rev. 17219).

```
    4352 18:13:38 ERROR xDB unavailable when submitting contact.
Exception: Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.XdbUnavailableException
Message: xDB unavailable
Source: Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.ExecuteWithExceptionHandling[T](Func`2 func)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<LoadContact>b__0()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.Monitor[T](OperationPerformanceMonitorBase monitor, Func`1 operation)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository.LoadContact(ID contactId)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository.MergeTemporaryContact(Contact contact)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository.SaveContact(Contact contact)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager.SubmitContact(Contact contact, Contact& realContact)

Nested Exception

Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: An error occurred while sending the request.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.Get[TEntity](IXdbContext context, IEntityReference`1 reference, ExpandOptions expandOptions, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.GetContactByIdentifier(IXdbContext xdbContext, String source, String identifier)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.ExecuteWithExceptionHandling[T](Func`2 func)

Nested Exception

Exception: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.ConnectionTimeoutException
Message: A task was canceled.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.CollectionBatchWebApiClient.<ExecuteBatch>d__11.MoveNext()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException
Message: A task was canceled.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Is xDB enabled?

Comment: Does it need to be? I couldn't find any documentation mentioning xDB as a prerequisite.

Comment: This is not SXA related.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, Any update??

Answer (score 0):

Check XDB Database installed successfully before installing SXA.